# How to copy/write in excel sheet using rubyXL gem. Please advice

Tags: rubyxl

I am using the below option 'add'

```
worksheet1.add(2, 6, "A1")
```

I need to copy the text A1 in (2,6).
 Error message is get is **"undefined method `add' for # (NoMethodError)"**

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Cells**

`worksheet.add_cell(0, 0, 'A1')`      # Sets cell A1 to string "A1"

`worksheet.add_cell(0, 1, '', 'A1')`  # Sets formula in the cell B1 to '=A1'

https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL